# Search for the nth 3d pentagonal numbers(challenge)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

There are square numbers, we can imagine these as a square of dots

Squ(n) $= n^2$

There are triangle numbers with we can imagine as a triangle of dots

tri(n) $=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

There are pentagonal numbers we can imgaine these as a pentagon of dots

Pent(n) $= \frac{3n^2 - n}{2}$

Square numbers have a three dimensional counterpart that are cubic numbers, so do triangular numbers.

The question is what is the nth 3D pentagonal number?

Comment: What is a 3D pentagon? Maybe a dodecahedron?

Comment: What is the three dimensional counterpart of triangular numbers? Tetrahedron?

Comment: @velutluna http://i.imgur.com/sVcsYDT.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [On Regular Polytope Numbers](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-01/S0002-9939-02-06710-2/S0002-9939-02-06710-2.pdf), Kim extends the notion of figurate numbers to 3-D solids. The [Dodecahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedral_number) seem to be what you describe, and are counted by 
$$
D_n=\frac{n(3n-1)(3n-2)}{2}
$$